# How to define LCA(Least Common Ancestor)(of two nodes) in case of a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, least-common-ancestor

I googled and tried to find about LCA(of two nodes) in a graph, but unfortunately, I didn't find much descriptive and understandable content.

So please can someone elaborate the LCA in a graph(both directed and undirected)?

Comment: What would the ancestor of a node be in an undirected graph?  Asking for a friend.

Comment: Do you want to find the LCA once, or lots of times for the same graph? Do you know anything about the max number of children a node in the graph can have?

Comment: @Dave  actually i want to know about LCA in graph, i have the idea of LCA in tree. But in case of graph i am getting confused...

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal If it's a directed acyclic graph there may be some optimization you can do, otherwise BFS from both nodes, maintaining constant distance from the source node and looking for common nodes have been reached (ravenspoint's answer) is good.

Answer (score 0):

To find the closest common ancestor to two nodes in a **directed** graph, do breadth first search upwards from each node.  Add each node as it is visited to a vector of nodes, one for each search.  When the searches are completed find the the first common node in the two vectors.

Optimization:  pause the searches when they increment their depth.  If a common node has been found, stop, otherwise continue to the next depth.